# Converting from one numpy dtype to another in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
import datetime
import pytz

refdate=datetime.datetime(2019,1,1,0,0,0,tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
for obj in datetime_list:
    print(obj)
    print(refdate)
    dt= obj-refdate


obj='2019-12-05T16:41:55.176647'

refdate='2019-01-01 00:00:00+00:00'
```

How can I cast one of these dates to perform the subtraction? One is `dtype('M8[us]')` and the other is `dtype('O')`

Comment: Please complete your question with a [minimal complete example](/help/mcve).

Comment: The `M8` is also called `np.datetime64`.  You can do subtraction, producing a `np.timedelta64`.  But  the 'O' type one, is a Python object, a `datetime.datetime`.  Have you tried `np.datetime64(refdate)`?